# Simplifying redux thunk actions with typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, redux, redux-thunk

I am currently using redux thunk along with typescript in my project and I am wondering if there are ways to simplify the code. As of right now this cleanest way to create these actions I have found:

```
export function apiRequestDispatcher(status: string, payload?: any ): ModalActionTypes["API_REQUEST"] {
  return {
    type: "API_REQUEST",
    status: status,
    payload: payload,
  }
}

export const sendEmail = (messageDetails: IContactForm): ThunkAction<Promise<ModalActionTypes["API_REQUEST"]>, ModalActionTypes["API_REQUEST"], undefined> => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(apiRequestDispatcher("pending"));
    return Request
    .post("/api/email")
    .send(messageDetails)
    .set("accept", "json")
    .then((response: Request.Response) => {
      return dispatch(apiRequestDispatcher("success", response));
    }).catch((error) => {
      return dispatch(apiRequestDispatcher("error", error));
    });
  };
}
```

with my types defined as:

```
export type ModalActionTypes = { 
    MODAL_TOGGLE: { 
        modalName: string;
        type: string; 
    },
    MODAL_ON_CHANGE: { 
        type: string;
        formName: string;
        inputName: string;
        inputValue: string;
    },
    API_REQUEST: {
        type: string;
        status: string;
        payload?: any;
    }
};
```

the part that i am most curious about simplifying is:

```
export const sendEmail = (messageDetails: IContactForm): ThunkAction<Promise<ModalActionTypes["API_REQUEST"]>, ModalActionTypes["API_REQUEST"], undefined> => {
```

out of all the examples I have found the code above seems to have the least amount of repetition, but that line i pointed out above is really hard to understand for new comers and it throws me off as well. Can that and other aspects of the code be cut down?

for reference this is the official type definition for redux thunk actions:

```
export type ThunkAction<R, S, E> = (dispatch: Dispatch<S>, getState: () => S,
                                    extraArgument: E) => R;
```

Comment: Except for defining a few type aliasses to hide away the uglyness don't think you can do better

Comment: So your saying I can put all the thunk action stuff into a single type with a name like "type ISendEmailThunkAction = ThunkAction<Promise<ModalActionTypes["API_REQUEST"]>, ModalActionTypes["API_REQUEST"], undefined>" ... I guess that could work

Comment: Yeah, that is one type, also maybe  `type ApiRequest=ModalActionTypes["API_REQUEST"]` as that looks to be used a lot or  `type ApiRequest<T extends { API_REQUEST : any } >= T["API_REQUEST"]`  if this is a common pattern..

Answer (score 0):

It definitely can be done, but this easily can become really opinionated. I am yet to find a "stardard recommended way".

I'm gonna link my playground project here, don't consider it a "reference" since I'm far from being Dan Abramov ;) . [example](https://github.com/wkrueger/muderrrno/blob/new2/src/timesheet/reducers/index.ts)

Here I declare my action types as a type union. (The main issue in this project is that I use them directly on the dispatchers -aka: action creators are optional- which can be considered an anti-pattern.)

```
export type OtherActions =
  | {
      type: "WEEK_IS_LOADING"
    }
  | {
      type: "REPLACE_WEEK"
      monday: Date
      entries: T.Timesheet_Stored[]
      projects: T.Project[]
    }
```

Here I ended up baking up a dispatch type because the default one doesn't seem to validate which action you throw in.

```
export type ThunkFunction<Actions, StateT> = (
  dispatcher: AnyDispatcher<Actions, StateT>,
  getState: () => StateT
) => void | Promise<void>

export interface AnyDispatcher<Actions, State> {
  (i: Actions): void
  (fn: ThunkFunction<Actions, State>): void
}
```

The thunk actions themselves are wrapped in an "error catcher" which will dispatch an error action if something is thrown inside (I guess this behavior will be probably replaced with other thing once I start getting into redux-saga). This "error catcher" also gives inference to the functions declared inside so you only need to type what is necessary.

```
export const Creators = errorWrapper<ActionsT, AppStateT>()({
  Init: () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    await Creators.Replace(new Date())(dispatch)
    dispatch({ group: "OTHER", type: "RECOVER_TRACKING_STATE" })
    await Creators.TrackingRefresh()(dispatch, getState)
  },
```

Besides my personal things, I'm also linking this project recently commented on reddit: [redoodle](https://github.com/palantir/redoodle) which is specifically targeted at making redux+TS easier. Still didn't test it but seems interesting. Out of the box it already features clean ways to create action creators with less keystrokes and without losing typings.